# Face Selection Masking for Painting not Working because Blender Tools Paint Outside those Areas?

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I have a model that I unwrap using "smart uv project".  None of the UV's are overlapping but they are squeezed somewhat close together, even when I set the island margin to 1.  I then click "Face selection masking for painting" in the Texture Paint mode, and it seems like it's going to work-- I can right-click on particular faces and paint onto those faces.

But: when I paint on faces, the paint goes past the lines of the UV, there's spill-over into the in between space. Face-selection isn't setting up a mask. And if another UV is there, that means other parts of the model are getting paid because of that spillover that I never wanted to be painted.  This seems like it will be an issue even if I unwrap it manually with seams and what have you since the issue isn't my unwrap-- it's that when I try to paint, it doesn't stick to within the lines.

(Larger goal: I want to go face by face and add colors to the different faces, ideally using some kind of fill tool-- I think I could use different materials, but that would be disadvantageous for later use in Unity(?).)

(My issue is also [detailed here](http://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/2zli4r/beginner_question_re_fill_tool_texturing_issue/)).

Comment: the faces are overlapping in your UV

Comment: You are right that the faces overlapped in earlier attempts at unwrapping.  But after those, I smart UV unwrapped and even when I move the faces of UVs away from any other UV, I can see that when I paint in them, the paint is going past the boundaries of the UV.  The paint is not staying within the boundaries of the UV.  There are too many UVs to move each one away from the others one at a time, without it taking forever.

Comment: see [this answer it may explain what's happening](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27247/5113)

Comment: Not the same problem, and none of the suggested solutions work.

Comment: then you should update your question  add images and a sample file